# React doesn't send entries to DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am making an AJAX request inside my `export default class List extends React Component`. It works fine and I see the requested array being returned in the form of:

[{...}, {...}, ...]

where each object inside the return is structured like this:

```
{
  description: "bla",
  id: "5b4915c37ae56418fcddb88f",
  link: "www.website.com",
  name: "bla",
  position: "bla",
  requirements: {
     age: 99, 
     citizenship: "bla", 
     degree: "bla"
  },
  salary: "1",
  state: "bla"
}
```

The return is set in the component's state. My render function looks like this:

```
render() {
    let entries = this.state.listEntries

    let mapper = entries.forEach((item,index) => {
        console.log(entries)
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                {item.name}
                {item.position}
            </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className="listWrapper">
            <HeaderBar props={this.state.props}/>
            <ul className="list">
                {mapper}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

React doesn't show the `item.name` or `item.position`, or any other item entry in the DOM. It seems like such a simple problem, but I just can't figure out what the issue is. There is no error in the console, it just doesn't display.

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `forEach` does not return anything you should use `map` for this kind of situations. Also, using `index` as a `key` can cause some problems, so you can use `item.id` instead of `index`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    listEntries: [
      {
        description: "bla",
        id: "5b4915c37ae56418fcddb88f",
        link: "www.website.com",
        name: "bla1",
        position: "bla1",
        requirements: {
          age: 99,
          citizenship: "bla",
          degree: "bla"
        },
        salary: "1",
        state: "bla"
      },
      {
        description: "bla",
        id: "5b4915c37ae56468fcddb88f",
        link: "www.website.com",
        name: "bla2",
        position: "bla2",
        requirements: {
          age: 99,
          citizenship: "bla",
          degree: "bla"
        },
        salary: "1",
        state: "bla"
      }
    ]
  }
  render() {
    let entries = this.state.listEntries

    let mapper = entries.map((item) => {
      console.log(entries)
      return (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
          {item.position}
        </li>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div className="listWrapper">
        <ul className="list">
          {mapper}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what kind of problems are we talking about for key={index} ?

Comment: Explained here: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318